# How to make sure that the data is always up-to-date on a API based Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

After authentication and authorization steps I get some data of the logged-in user and put it to the Vuex.

It is handy to access this mostly used variables, but what if changes something of the data on API side? The data is feed by another resources/websites. So, there is always a possibility of change.

Furthermore, I have multiple calls that have a different type of user data.

I do the same call after each hard page refresh and rewrite the Vuex data.

Does it make sense? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have control of the APIs? Have you researched [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or Webhooks or API polling?

Comment: WebSocket was the first thing that came in my head. I have partially control the APIs. They are developed in our company. Is it the best practice?

Comment: It really depends on the the server technology you are using, but WebSocket can be a great option for realtime communication. This may not be the best forum for "best practices". I'd recommend trying options and seeing what works best for your application and environment. If you have any issues specifically implementing those strategies, this would be a great place to ask questions.